# How to support multi-touch feature on the activity in android 2.1?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, multi-touch

I want to support multi-touch feature in my application which is having set of activities, how to achieve it programmatically in Android 2.1 version?

Please share with some sample code.

Comment: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/06/making-sense-of-multitouch.html

Comment: Hope it helps http://www.mysecretroom.com/www/programming-and-software/android-multi-touch-handling

Comment: thanks a lot for sharing the link, one silly doubt i am having is :, do I need to implement it in all activities or if i implement in my base class activity will make all activities multitouch??

Comment: as per me we can use base class activity, thas good for us.

Comment: Thanks once again Mike to sharing the link, I am able to implement multitouch in the same way it was given in the link but one doubt i m having: I am having activity with Linear layout and inside that there are several linear layouts and image buttons, text views are there so in this case i want to ipml multitouch in such a way tat user can zoom in-zoom out screen as a whole not one component so user can resize the whole activity screen using theirs fingers.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can do it with newer versions of Android:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
    super.onTouchEvent(e);

    switch (MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(e)) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
            //Do action
            break;

    }

    return true;

}
```

(`onTouchEvent` is available in Views; not activities)

There is no need to call `setOnTouchListener` because this is called no matter what whenever the screen is touched. By overriding it you can customize it with touch events. Keep in mind the normal onTouchListener does **not** support multitouch